# startActivity of other app with sourceBounds (like launchers do it)

Tags: android, android-activity, start-activity

I want to write my own launcher scratch and therefore I need to start apps based on their package name. I want that other apps open from the position the app is started inside my launcher like most launchers do it. Therefore I set the `sourceBounds` inside the intent. But this does not work. I still see sliding animations when starting gmail e.g. and I tested gmail with another launcher and this app does support `sourceBounds`.

Here's the code, does anybody know what I'm missing?

I checked that bounds are set correctly and they are.

**Code**

```
fun startApp(activity: AppCompatActivity, packageName: String, bounds: Rect?) {
    val intent = activity.packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName)!!
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
    bounds?.let {
        intent.sourceBounds = it
    }
    val options: Bundle? = null
    Log.d("BOUNDS", "bounds: $bounds")
    activity.startActivity(intent, options)
}
```

Comment: Have you tried [Intent.setSourceBounds()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#setSourceBounds(android.graphics.Rect))? Do note that above doc mentions that it is up to the receiver of said intent if it will be used: "This can be used as a hint to the receiver for animations and the like."

Comment: My code shows that I'm setting the source bounds. And yes, the receiver must use this data and as I wrote, I tested it with gmail and gmail does work correctly in another launcher

Comment: I am asking because I have not seen a `sourceBounds` attribute for class `Intent`, neither in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent), nor in the [source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/content/Intent.java).

Comment: That's just kotlin (`sourceBounds` relates to `setSourceBounds` and `getSourceBounds` in java)

Comment: Damn, sorry about that. Kotlin is new to me, so I did not know about this feature. I only used Java back in the days. Thanks for the info. Also, I am out of ideas as to what might be happening.